# Rules that allow for local port reuse by an application

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel

For a TCP server with following structure:

```
main(){
    socket();
    bind();
    listen();
    while(1){
       accept();
       fork();
       if(child)
          Process;
    }
}
```

It creates a new socket for each client and communicates with all clients using the same port. Thus, all sockets bind to the same port.

I came across following [comments](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.33.5/include/net/inet_hashtables.h#L48) when reading the kernel code (2.6.33.5):

```
48/* There are a few simple rules, which allow for local port reuse by
49 * an application.  In essence:
50 *
51 *      1) Sockets bound to different interfaces may share a local port.
52 *         Failing that, goto test 2.
53 *      2) If all sockets have sk->sk_reuse set, and none of them are in
54 *         TCP_LISTEN state, the port may be shared.
55 *         Failing that, goto test 3.
56 *      3) If all sockets are bound to a specific inet_sk(sk)->rcv_saddr local
57 *         address, and none of them are the same, the port may be
58 *         shared.
59 *         Failing this, the port cannot be shared.
60 *
```

So, for the TCP server above, is it the third rule which it matches?

Comment: Regardless of linux's implementation, a TCP connection is distinguished by the quintuple: (protocol, local addr, local port, remote addr, remote port).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 1 plus N sockets playing in this game.

1 The **listening socket**, which was passed to `bind()` and `listen()`. Only this socket is bound to the port on which the server listens.

2 All the N **connected sockets** created by the N 'processes' of the clients connecting to the server, and being returned by `accept()`. Those sockets are serving the connections to the clients. Such sockets do **not** listen in the sense the **listening socket** does.

The rules you quoted apply to the **listening socket** only.

So if you only run one instance of your server the third rule *does not* apply, as it `bind()`s only one socket to `listen()` on the server's port.